# How do I avoid using the dead letter queue using Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have a in/out producer in Camel that only hangs around for a limited time before getting back to the caller.  Some times this naturally results in a dead letter item and an exception being caught by the caller when the response is late.

What I would like to do is have the caller receive a timeout message instead of an exception and the item to never end up in the DLQ.  Naturally I could put a listener on the DLQ but as the item has a home to go to it shouldn't really ever get to the DLQ.

Does anyone have a pattern for this?  How would it be done?  There are redundant consumer patterns (see Camel in Action [link](http://amzn.com/1935182366)) but this is kind of a combined producer/consumer problem generated by the in/out pattern.

Comment: try posting it at camel-nabble archive.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using the Dead Letter Channel error handler, try using the noErrorHandler - http://camel.apache.org/error-handler

Comment: Nice idea.  The issue is that it once again labels something as an error or exception when it is part of normal processing.  But it certainly appears to move in the right direction.  

Ultimately this issue is solved using a delegation thread that stays alive longer than the creating thread.  This delegate then handles the response case where the delegator has gone back to the client.  

Naturally the delegate can be constructed using Camel. :o)